# Black screen after login?

Tags: 13.10, login

I had 12.04LTS and recently decided to upgrade to 13.10. 12.10 wouldn't ever start up and all I could access was the GRUB and the terminal, so I upgraded to 13.10 from there. I have a cd with 12.04 on it but I do not have the others on a disk and I cannot make one because I do not have a cd large enough to make one. After 13.10 was installed, it worked alright. There were black bars around every field and I could not acess the terminal at all. I restarted it and after I put in my password, the screen goes blank and after a moment or so there would be two boxes that say something along the lines of a system problem being detected and I could move the cursor to click either cancel or report the problem. Nothing would happen after that, but by using ctrl + alt + t I could access the terminal. I looked at a few other topics that others seemed to be having the same problem as I did but all of the solutions that were being suggested didn't work for some reason. I don't want to reinstall the system because I couldn't create a backup of my files before this happened.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I have faced. This is the problem with the unity 3d of ubuntu 12 LTS to Ubuntu 13.

Restart your system. After getting login page change your unity 3d to Unity then give the password.

After that you got your desktop. Repeating these login again you can also login with Unity 3d will take you to your desktop.

Comment: I don't have this option. I think that when it updated it didn't install a lot of packages and unity was one of them for some reason. I have tried installing them but it keeps failing.

Comment: `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` returned: `... Not blacklisted: no ... Unity 3D support: no`  Next I ran: `lspci | grep VGA` returned: `GA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV36 [GeForce FX 5700LE]`  Even installing NVIDIA drivers resulted in black screen after logging in.  Turns out unity does not work with my graphics card. My solution was not to run unity and run gnome.  `sudo apt-get gnome-session-flashback` and reboot.  At the login screen click the icon to the upper right of name and select GNOME Flashback (Metacity).